# how can I prevent errors with nested data in an array if it is empty?

Tags: javascript

I have this example:

```
var data={
  city:{
    street:{
      houses:[]
    }
  }
}

alert(data.city.street.houses?.[0].person);
```

```js
    var data={
      city:{
        street:{
          houses:[]
        }
      }
    }

    alert(data.city.street.houses?.[0].person);
```

this would show an error because it does not exist `houses[0]`, how can I avoid having errors but in case `houses[0]` does exist, continue with the nesting?

doing this, I am getting errors:

[image]

how can I do it?

Comment: Sorry, can you please clarify your question?

Comment: I think you put the optional chaining operator in the wrong place. You might have meant to put it *after* the `[0]`

Comment: @MrMythical I added some details, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just add another chaining operator after the array item reference:

```js
var data = {
  city: {
    street: {
      houses: []
    }
  }
}

let res = data.city.street.houses?.[0];
res = res != undefined ? res.person : 'no value';
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I add some details in my question, can you see again please?

Comment: @yavgz something is wrong with your IDE if it's giving an error with this answer. Make sure you're on the latest version

Comment: I know that maybe it is out of the scope of the question, but maybe you know how to help me, I can make a ternary operator in the case that the nesting becomes undefined?

Comment: @yavgz I've updated my answer.